# Python update fields with matching name

Tags: python, django, model

I have three (or more in the future) integer fields with similar names:

```
class Statistic(models.Model):
    first_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    second_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    third_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I get a variable that tells me which one to update. If `variable == "first"` increment `first_count`, if `variable == "second"` then increment `second_count`... I am wondering, if there is a better way to do this?

To paint you a better picture, this is what i would want to do:

`Statistic.variable+"_count" = Statistic.variable+"_count" + 1 #increment value`
But i do realize, that this wouldnt work and would also be a very bad practice.

Is there a simpler solution I am not seeing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just make a single field `count` and increment it?

Comment: I have to keep three separate counts